# Opening a new Atom window and wait for it to exit before continuing?

Tags: git, atom-editor

I am trying to configure [Atom](http://atom.io) as my text editor for git commit messages on the command line.

Several pages, including [this one on Github](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/) says to use this:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

This works but only if I don't have an atom window open already. If I do, it seems the new atom process simply passes on all the arguments to the existing process and terminates, leaving the `--wait` option useless.

This is on Windows 10, I don't know how this behaves on other operating systems but my question is specifically for Windows unless this is a general problem.

So when I execute my git commit command, and no atom process is running, this happens:

1. `git commit`
2. Atom spawns, opening up the editor with the commit message template
3. When I save **and close the atom window**, git continues and reports:

   ```
   [master 3745ef7] xyz
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
   ```

However, if I already have an atom window open when I do the above, this happens:

1. `git commit`
2. Atom spawns, just as it did before
3. But simultaneously, git reports this and exits:

   ```
   Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
   ```

My "passes on the arguments to the existing process" remark above is conjecture and may not be what happens at all.

I've also tried this:

```
atom --wait --new-window
```

Which does indeed bring up a completely new window in addition to the original window, with only the guide and my commit message file, but this too has the same problem, if I already had an existing process I get the new window but git terminates with an error because `atom.exe` terminated.

So, is there a way to coach atom to behave properly in my environment and this situation?

Comment: Does it still occur? On MacOS, `git commit` spawns a new window and waits. So, it's maybe only Windows (10) related.
Did you already [file an issue in their repository](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/new)  Could be that the developers don't know about that,
 yet. See this [related issue from 2018-02-14](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/16740)

Comment: In which shell are you running `git commit`? Did you try instead of using `git config` to set the environment variable `EDITOR` (for `cmd.exe`) or add `export EDITOR='atom --wait'` to your `~/.bashrc`?